# Migrate Magento EE 1.14.3.1 to Magento CE 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration

How to migrate **Magento Enterprise** Version 1.14.3.1 to **Magento Community** Version 2.1.7?

I am not getting perfect solution for migrate from M1 Enterprise to M2 Community.

Official [Data-migration-tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate.html) is not providing solution for this so please help me to migrate Step-by-Step.

Comment: try data-migration-tool of magento and which data you want to migrate: Orders and customer or all data?

Comment: Magento Data migration tool is not providing feature to migrate From Enterprise to Community

I need to migrate following data
1. Categories
2. Products
3. Customers
4. Orders

Comment: Check with this :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186493/magento-2-migrate-from-m1-enterprise-to-m2-community

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
I have already tried provided steps but facing lot of issue with product's attribute and others.

So I need alternate smooth solution/tools (Free or paid)

Answer (score 4):

The Data-migration-tool does not come with such functionality out of the box (and I guess it won't ever have) for obvious reasons not to mention the advantages and features you will loose if you switch from EE to CE.

But leaving this aside and focusing on the technical question, if I were you I would try to extend the tool to do what I want.

How? you may ask.

The data migration tool transfers data from a source database to a destination database and it uses a set of config files where you can specify in what order, what data and how you want your data to be transferred. That is all it does.

By default it comes with 3 modes that need to be executed in order (if you are planning to do a full migration):

- **Settings**: Migrates the system configuration and website-related settings
- **Data**: Migrates database assets in bulk like catalog, customers, orders...
- **Delta**: Migrates incremental changes (for example, orders and inventory)

This said, I would start by creating the set of config files needed using the ones already there.

[image]

Then, I would first focus on migrate only `settings`.

Once I'm happy with the results, I would try to migrate `data`, commenting out the steps I don't need, for example `<step title="Log Step">` or `<step title="VisualMerchandiser Step">` (it does not exists in CE).

This does not pretend to be a step by step guide (I'm afraid, I don't even have an environment with a 1.14.3.1 database right now to try myself) and of course it will require a lot of trail and error until you get the expected result, but the good news is that is possible :)

Hope it helps.

**Important:** remember to backup your databases (specially source db) before you start, so you can perform as many tests you need with the confidence that you won't loose your information.

**Further readings**:

- [How Migration Works](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-overview-how.html)
- [Data Migration Tool Technical Specification](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use Additional features of EE.
And Magento 2 CE giving some advanced features so I wish to move M2 CE.

So trying to move M1 EE To M2 CE

Comment: Well, now you should have at least an idea of how to customise Data Migration Tool to migrate data from one to another, so good luck with that.

Comment: But not getting proper solution yet,
With the migration tool facing lot of issue with product's attribute and others. So I need alternate smooth solution/tools (Free or paid).

Comment: have you get success  on magento1  ee to magento 2 opensource version on this way?