# Migrate from Magento Commerce 1.14.2.2 to Magento Open Source 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, migration

I want to migrate from Magento Commerce 1.14.2.2 to Magento Open Source 2.3.3

I already read [Migrate Magento EE 1.14.3.1 to Magento CE 2.1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/migrate-magento-ee-1-14-3-1-to-magento-ce-2-1-7) but it is not sufficient to achieve goal

As per my finding in above solution, we can create another folder `commerce-to-opensource` in migration tool by copying `commerce-to-commerce` folder and adjust config.xml, map.xml etc.

I tried above solution but:

```
- category is migrated but without category name and URL, 
- order is not migrated
- product is migrated but not opening in Admin and giving error `this product does not exist`
```

Another solution is to first downgrade from magento Commerce 1.14.2.2 to Magento Open Source  1.9.4.3 and then migrate from Open Source to Open Source

Any help Or suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Because orders and categories are missing after the migration, so it isn't an efficient tool, I think you need to use another automated migration tool to transfer your data. 
You want to open products migrated in Admin without error, run this query:

```
update
`catalog_product_entity`
set sku = '' where sku is null
```

Hope this helps